# what do you need to do for RSA securid integration into your web application?

Tags: asp.net, authentication, rsa, securid

We have clients who have RSA securid deployed within their premises and we want to sell our product to them. We need to integrate with their 2 factor authentication setup for authentication into our product.

We have an asp.net (C#) web based application that is exposed to the clients and which needs to support authentication using their own securid setup.

Can someone please help me in getting this support implemented? Pointers to existing documentation are also welcome.

I searched through the queries on this forum and found that most are talking about giving token generation mechanism on your web application itself but I don't think that is the approach that is required for our use case.

Answer (score 1):

have you checked out the web sdk from RSA?

http://www.emc.com/security/rsa-securid/rsa-securid-software-authenticators/web-sdk.htm

Comment: can I use the sdk to specify the securid server and get authentication support?